# CouchDB - Overwrite deleted documents from backup database to original database

Tags: database, couchdb, replication, cloudant

Replicate the documents which marked deleted on original database, but that document is present into the replicated database. Now I am performing the replication, but the deleted document is not restoring from the replicated database to original database even though document is present.

For Example,
Database A contains,

Document 1

Document 2

Replicated database A to database B

Marked document 1 as deleted

Now performing replication from database B to database A

But the document 1 is not replicating to database A.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you marked document 1 in database A as deleted and then replicated from B to A.

In that case, the replication will transfer no data because there are no changes in B (the Source) that A (the destination) hasn't got. So consequently, document 1 is not going to "reappear" in A.

There is a replication guide [in this document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-replication-guide)